# google maps api v2 out of memory error

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

i have a huge memory problem in my app. i am using google map api v2 with `ClusterManager` and custom markers. i supply an image via call to `markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));` for each marker based on its category. the problem is: after several screen rotations my app crashes because of OOM error:

```
05-14 11:04:12.692  14020-30201/rokask.rideabike E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 1627608 free bytes and 1589KB until OOM"
05-14 11:04:12.722  14020-30201/rokask.rideabike E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 19179
Process: rokask.rideabike, PID: 14020
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 1627608 free bytes and 1589KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:939)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.b.ak.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.b.as.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.x.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.l.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.l.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.cv.f(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.cv.run(Unknown Source)
```

i have a `LruCache` object with my `Bitmap`s, it means that i do not recreate them, but reuse them. i can clearly see that every `Bitmap` object is taken from the cache, not from elsewhere. However, if the `Bitmap` is not in the cache yet (first time loading) i load it from my app's internal storage, but it only happnes when the `Bitmap` is laoded the first time. i keep the instance of the `LruCache` in a retained `Fragment` instance and pass it to my custom `DefaultClusterRenderer<MyObject>` object everytime the `Activity` is recreated and map needs to be redrawn.

this is my `DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem>` extension:

```
public class DotRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Dot> {
private final String internalStorageDir;
private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> lruCache;

public DotRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap googleMap, ClusterManager<Dot> clusterManager,
                   LruCache<String, Bitmap> lruCache, String internalStorageDir)
{
    super(context, googleMap, clusterManager);
    //this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
    this.internalStorageDir = internalStorageDir;
    this.lruCache = lruCache;
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Dot mapObject, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    markerOptions.title(mapObject.getTitle());
    String id = Integer.toString(mapObject.getTypeId());
    //
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(id);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "reading bitmap from storage.");
        Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> bitmapEntry
                = BitmapManager.getBitmapFromStorage(internalStorageDir, id);
        if (bitmapEntry != null) {
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapEntry.getValue()));
            addBitmapToMemCache(id, bitmapEntry.getValue());
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "reading bitmap from cache.");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }
}

private void addBitmapToMemCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        lruCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return lruCache.get(key);
}
}
```

this is the code inside my `Activity` where i start loading the map (this code is executed everytime screen orientation changes):

```
    ClusterManager<Dot> clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, googleMap);
    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(
            new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<Dot>() {
                @Override
                public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(Dot dot) {
                    int id = dot.getId();
                    String title = dot.getTitle();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clicked marker with id " + id
                            + " and title " + title + ".");
                    Intent infoWindowActivityIntent =
                            new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoWindowActivity.class);
                    infoWindowActivityIntent.putExtra("dotId", id);
                    infoWindowActivityIntent.putExtra("dotTitle", title);
                    startActivity(infoWindowActivityIntent);
                }
            });
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager);

    DotRenderer dotRenderer =
            new DotRenderer(getApplicationContext(), googleMap, clusterManager,
                    lruCache, this.getFilesDir().toString());
    clusterManager.setRenderer(dotRenderer);
```

the memory keeps increasing with every screen rotation, the more i zoom in the map (the more markers are shown) the more amount of memory is added to my app's heap when i rotate the screen until application crashes.

sometimes the error is not like above, but shows that OOM happened at this line in my `DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItam>` extension `markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));`.

if i disable custom marker icon (remove all the `Bitmap` related code) the memory problem vanishes. please help me to find what causes this OOM to appear.

Comment: Did u tried these on your Main Activity?    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }                                                                                                               I mean in the activity or fragment, which the mapview added...

Comment: comment edited.. check it...

Comment: no, i didn't, but i tried `System.gc()`. it doesn't help... i gues they are pretty much the same.

Comment: Try this code and let me knw the result... Al the best....

Comment: i don't think this is a clean workaround. i don't even use `MapView`. i use `GoogleMap`

Comment: try this code in your manifest....   android:largeHeap = true

Comment: i've already tried it, but it only makes the app last longer until it still finally crashes...

Comment: Just adding my comment for anyone in future to find - System.gc() does not seem to be making any difference. Looking at the profiler in Android Studio, before calling gc(), "graphics" was occupying 198.1MB, after gc() 198.2MB, so no difference. However, calling map.clear() made a huge difference. Before map.clear(), "graphics" was 198.1MB and after clear() became 73.1MB, a major reduction.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem trying to run an app on demo mode for a few hours at a time. No matter what I tried, after 30 minutes, I would see this crash without a readable stack report.

I tried System gc(), detaching the fragment, singleton activities, updating google play services to the latest, clearing references to overlays, attaching map lifecycle to activity and what not.
After many failed attempts and a lot of frustration I finally found something that worked. It's not a fix for the map bug, but it kept my app from crashing:

```
    <application
    ...
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: I spent hours before bumping into this thread. I used a combination of the three answers: largeHeap, System.gc and map.clear. It worked

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" will help increase memory usage for your app, and won't help to resolve your problem. Without largeHeap mean largeHeap false your app can stand for 30 minutes. So with largeHeap true just let's your app last a bit longer without crash just like one or two hours ...etc.

Comment: Correct, that's why I said "It's not a fix".

Answer (score 1):

Alright... I think this should work...

Add `googleMap.clear()` whenever you want to reset the map.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: already tried this too. no luck. i've even tried setting the icon to default for each marker individually and then remove them one by one in `Activity`'s `onDestroy()`.